# How to match a list to a user input

Tags: python

Alright, I want to make some python 3 code that can match a user input in a set list from a .txt file.

The txt file reads: [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)

```
Userinput = input ("What URL do you want to search up?: ")
a_file = open("SAMPLE.txt", "r")

Websites_Blacklist = []
for line in a_file:
  stripped_line = line.strip()
  line_list = stripped_line.split()
  Websites_Blacklist.append(line_list)


#a_file.close()

#Below is for testing
print(Websites_Blacklist)
print(Userinput)   

if Userinput in Websites_Blacklist:
    print ("This Website has been blacklisted")
else:
    print ("This website is fine")
```

I feel really dumb not knowing this but would love some help <3

Comment: What is the issue with your code? [ask]

Comment: What is your issue, specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

You can set a flag when the condition met is True, the break out of the loop.

```
with open("sample.txt",'r') as files:
    x=input("Enter the name of the website: ")
    found=False
    for line in files:
        if x==line.strip():
            found=True
            break
    if found:
        print('Website is black listed.')
    else:
        print('Website is safe.')
```

Sample.txt:

```
www.website.com
www.google.com 
www.youtube.com
```

Output:

```
#===Run 1
Enter the name of the website: www.youtube.com
Website is black listed.

#====Run 2
Enter the name of the website: www.office.com
Website is safe.
```

Comment: Wow, that was really fast!

Comment: @FullOnGamer, most welcome. If it solves the problem, please accept and upvote the answer ```:-)```

Comment: I would upvote it but I still need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, I have marked that answer as solved :)

Comment: @FullOnGamer no problem. Thanks